# XAMPP MySQL error when trying to install Livezilla, invalid host or login! 1045: access denied for root@localhost

Tags: mysql, xampp

Fresh install of XAMPP and Livezilla, Livezilla creates the MySQL database as part of it's installation (if not already specified) which is what I have done. I have tried both 127.0.0.1 and localhost as the host but both give the same error.

> Can't connect to database. Invalid host or login! (1045: Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

Not too sure what the issue could be, my only assumption would be a permissions issue where Livezilla is being blocked from creating the DB for the Livezilla application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you tried the wrong infos. The hostname and password you are trying to enter are the ones related to MySQL and not to Livezilla Server Admin application.

Comment: thank you man, for some reason my mind escaped me. didnt have a password for my root so not specifying a pwd solved the issue.